# Relinux No default or ui configuration problem

Tags: vmware, custom-distributions, relinux

I installed ubuntu 12.04 and make some customization. Then i try to make iso using relinux however when i boot new iso it says no default or ui configuration error

I installed first ubuntu 12.04 in vmware fusion. Used relinux of course on vmware fusion.

Tried to boot new iso again with vmware fusion.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes, you are one of the few who managed to get relinux 0.4a1 to actually make an ISO =P Try using relinux 0.3a3 =)

(I was really sick when I coded 0.4a1, don't blame me XDD jk)